# How RAILS_ENV, config.assets.debug, and asset pipeline are related in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

We have UAT and production environment to run rails app. UAT runs app with RAILLS_ENV=uat and RAILS_ENV=production for production server. For deployment, we compile assets on local machine and copy everything to these servers so that we don't have to compile assets on UAT and production servers.

Now, I came to find that I have to run rails app with the same RAILS_ENV as the env that I specify at asset compile if I set config.assets.debug = true.
Otherwise, I get the following error.

```
ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable in Welcome#index

    Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
    (in /opt/myapp/app/assets/javascripts/ping.js.coffee)
```

For example, if I compile asset like below:

```
rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
```

and copying the compiles assets to the UAT server (where RAILS_ENV is uat) with config.assets.debug = true, it does not work with the error.

If I set config.assets.debug = false or run the app with RAILS_ENV=production, it works fine. But, I don't understand why different RAILS_ENV makes problem
when setting config.assets.debug = true.

Could anyone explain how they are related?

Comment: Do you have a JavaScript runtime environment installed on both your UAT and production machines? It may just be that one of the machines lacks that runtime. That point does not address the question, just your problem, though.

Comment: Eric, we don't have JavaScript runtime installed on UAT and production. If my understanding is correct, I don't have to install JS runtime on production/uat machine because they use compiled asset.

Comment: Is it working for you in UAT with debug set to false?

Comment: I have removed my answer, as it was completely useless to the question.

Comment: Have you considered the section on [local pre-compilation from the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#local-precompilation)? I have tried to pin point in the Rails or Sprockets source code, but I have not managed yet. Basically I suspect that the hashes generated for compiled assets depend on the RACK/RAILS environment.